# Efficiently apply custom function in specific date ranges to groups

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

I am to calculate a number of different centrality and spread indicators on multiple timeframes on a relatively large data set ~1million rows. I have had multiple different tries, but the algorithm that I end up at is still waaay too slow for my purpose.

Here is my current iteration:

```
ts_rollapply <- function(COI, DATE_COL, FUN, n, unit = c("day", "week", "month", "year"), verbose = FALSE, ...) {
  # Initiate Variables
  APPLY_FUNC <- match.fun(FUN = FUN)
  LAST_DATE <- last_date(DATE_COL, n = n, unit = match.arg(unit))
  result <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(COI))

  for(i in seq_along(COI)) {
    # Extract range from Column of Interest
    APPLY_RANGE <- COI[DATE_COL > LAST_DATE[i] & DATE_COL <= DATE_COL[i]]
    # Apply function to extracted range
    result[i] <- APPLY_FUNC(APPLY_RANGE, ...)
    if(verbose && i%%100 == 0) {
      ARL <- length(APPLY_RANGE)
      writeLines(sprintf("Last Date: %10s, Current Date: %10s, Iteration: %3d, Length: %3d, Mean: %.2f", 
                         LAST_DATE[i], DATE_COL[i], i, ARL, result[i]))
    }
  }

  result
}
```

Note that I have also made a helper function to extract certain time periods (last_date), which is implemented as follows:

```
last_date <- function(x, n = 1, unit = c("day", "week", "month", "year")) {
  require(lubridate)

  # Stop function if x is not Class Date.
  if(!is.Date(x)) stop("x is not class: Date")
  if(any(is.na(x))) stop("x contains NA")

  # Match unit and Perform Calculation
  unit <- match.arg(unit)
  result <- switch(unit,
         day = x - n,
         week = x - (7L*n),
         month = x %m-% months(n),
         year = x %m-% months(12L*n))

  result
}
```

The problem that I face is that the function work as intended when I run it on a small sample, but it fail (time-wise) when I scale it to the full dataset. And I cannot figure out whether it is the function implementation that I have made, which is slow. Or if it is that way in which I call the function in my data.table.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# Functions to apply -- I have multiple others, but these should work as example
functions <- c("mean", "median", "sd")

# Toy Data:
DT <- data.table(store = rep(1:10, each = 1000),
                 sales = rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 4500, sd = 2500),
                 date = rep(seq(ymd("2015-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 1000), 10))

# How i call the ts_rollapply function
DT[, paste("sales_quarter", functions, sep = "_") := lapply(functions, function(x) ts_rollapply(sales, date, x, n = 3, unit = "month", na.rm = T)), store]
```

Any help on how to speed up my computation would be much appreciated!

Comment: At a glance it looks like you're doing some rolling window operations. Are you familiar with `frollapply`?

Comment: Yes I am. But unfortunately, `frollapply` doesn't support subsetting with date ranges, hence the custom function. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to do a non-equi join

```
DT[, (cols) := 
    DT[.(STORE=STORE, START_DATE=DATE - 7L, END_DATE=DATE), 
        on=.(STORE, DATE>=START_DATE, DATE<=END_DATE),
        lapply(functions, function(f) get(f)(SALES)), by=.EACHI][, (1:3) := NULL]
    ]
```

A faster way should be to fill in the SALES for all dates and use `data.table::frollapply` as mentioned in the comments.

```
res <- DT[DT[, .(DATE=seq(min(DATE), max(DATE), by="1 day")), STORE], on=.(STORE, DATE)][,
    (cols) := lapply(functions, function(f) frollapply(SALES, 7L, f, na.rm=TRUE))]
DT[res, on=.(STORE, DATE), names(res) := mget(paste0("i.", names(res)))]
```

If the above suits your real-life problem, then we can create a function with it.

data:

```
library(data.table)    
functions <- c("mean", "median", "sd")
nr <- 1e6
DT <- data.table(STORE=rep(1:10, each=nr/10),
    SALES=rnorm(nr, 4500, 2500),
    DATE=rep(seq(as.IDate("2015-01-01"), by="day", length.out=nr/10), 10))
cols <- paste("sales_quarter", functions, sep = "_")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it is not quite what i'm looking for. You see, while your solution works fine with a fixed window - here `7L`, which I guess should represent the function applied weekly - a problem emerges when subtracting monthly periods, since these are not a fixed interval; 3 months is between 88-92 days dependent on the season.

Comment: As I see it, the method is similar in both methods; Method 1: `START_DATE = DATE-7L`  and in Method 2: `frollapply(SALES, 7L, .....)`. 

So Both methods assume that the duration between start and end can be expressed as a fixed value. Am I wrong?

Comment: u can change `DATE - 7L` to calculate your desired start date

Comment: You are completely right! 
I found that your first solution, combined with the last_date function to calculate the start date provides a x2 speed-up. Thank you very much for the help :-)

Comment: i would really prefer the `frollapply` method. you can be more precise with your numbers by handling the different number of days in diff months but u are calculating statistics, there is inherent uncertainty in the measures and this accuracy is going to matter more than the 3 days difference in your statistics

Comment: You are probably right, in terms of a general approach. But for my specific use-case, I belive the other method to be more appropriate. Still, I was wondering, if you could explain to me, the first join that you are doing in the `frollapply` method - is this just to ensure that all dates are present?

Comment: Yeah to ensure all dates are present